# privileged column not being shown

Tags: jsf-2, authorization

I want a rich:column to be visible just for Admin user(I am using auth-config.xml for authentification and privilegies), like this:

```
<rich:column rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('auctionAdmin')}">
```

but the column becames invisible for all users. I am using JSF 2.x and Wildfly Jboss for deployment

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, does your Admin user have the "auctionAdmin" role?

Comment: Yes. I have two files: "auction-roles.properties" and "auction-user.properties" referenced in the auth-config.xml. I've used the application-policy feature from org.jboss.security

Comment: Well (vol. 2 ;-])... Let me ask, are you SURE that `isUserInRole` returns good values for all users? I can't see how this can be a problem with JFS.  You can change `rendered` argument for the function which returns false every second time and I think it will work as expected.